# use an environment variable as JVM options

Tags: java, environment-variables, jvm-arguments

I am using DCEVM in a Java SE project, where I pass and works fine:

```
run.jvmargs=-XXaltjvm=dcevm -javaagent:D:\\libs\\hotswap-agent.jar
```

I would like to make this config **cross-platform** so I defined and tried to use an environment variable: 
hotswap_agent = D:\somepath\

```
run.jvmargs=-XXaltjvm=dcevm -javaagent:"%hotswap_agent%hotswap-agent.jar"
```

or

```
run.jvmargs=-XXaltjvm=dcevm -javaagent:%hotswap_agent%hotswap-agent.jar
```

but the VM cannot resolve this.

is it possible to do this? use an EV as VM option?
PD: I'm using Netbeans, on W10

Comment: It should work. Did you define your env variable *before* opening the command prompt or whatever you use to start your app?

Comment: yes, I checked opening cmd, echo %hotswap....% and returned the path

Answer (score 0):

After adding a EV, the IDE needs to be restarted.

PD: added the answer since this post reached 1k viewer recently